# Connecting to ArcGIS Server with IIS 7.5 (ArcObjects/COM)

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, arcgis-9.3

This code works fine on a development box, but fails in a server environment:

```
GISServerConnection gisServerConnection = new GISServerConnection();
gisServerConnection.Connect("localhost");
```

The exception is this:

```
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
at ESRI.ArcGIS.Server.IGISServerConnection.Connect(String machineName)
```

My best guess is that I need to add a user to the `agsusers` group. Our server (Server 2008 R2) uses IIS 7.5, so I tried adding the application pool identity `ASP.NET v4.0 Classic` to the group. This failed, so I tried adding `IUSR` to the group, which also failed.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group memberships don't take effect until the user logs out and back in. Can't really do that with an application pool identity, so I tried restarting the IIS service. That didn't help, so I rebooted the machine, which finally solved my problem.

Comment: I wonder if restarting the SOM would have worked.